# SSRS: Line chart over stacked bar chart

Tags: sql, reporting-services, charts, reportbuilder3.0

I'm trying to create a stacked bar chart with multiple data lines above it.

Current Chart:

[image: Current Chart]

My data looks like this:

[image: Dataset]

My report is set up to take 2 parameters: LOB (multi) and Metric (singular).

Chart Data Set Up:

[image: Chart Data Set Up]

In the chart under January, I should have 3 lines with data points 38.35, 55.09, and 26.68. Instead, what I'm getting is a summation of the 3 numbers.

I'm pretty new to SSRS, so I haven't been able to figure out how to get my 3 lines above the bar chart. Any help is appreciated.

Mock up:I would like for the lines to look like this, but the bars would still sum up like the chart above.  Seems like I would need to make the Bars ignore the Series grouping somehow.

[MockUp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q456B.png)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mock is showing, it doesn't relate to the sample data. January has 6 columns but your sample data only has 3 rows for January.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the drop down arrow next to metric rate and remove sum from the Metric_Rate field.

Comment: Doing that removes the summation, but still gives me one line with data points from each LOB.

Comment: Seems like I'd need to have a different line value for each LOB and hard code it for each LOB, but i can't seem to get my expression correct

Answer (score 0):

You said you were expecting three values under January, one for each LOB but you have not included LOB in and category groups so the chart assumes you want to aggregate everything down to the month level. If you add LOB to your category group you should see the data you need.

I took a subset of your data (just Jan - Mar) and just added a very simple chart. I moved the line onto the secondary Axis for clarity and simply added the LOB to the category group.

Here's the design.
[image]

And the final output.

[image]

I've not added the data labels but all points are shown.

**If this is not what you intended then please sketch up what you expect the final chart to look like based on your sample data.**

Comment: I tried putting LOB in to the Category Groups, the outcome is still the same.  The 3 values for the LOBs are summarized into one line instead of having 3 separate lines.

Comment: I've added what I'd kind of want my chart to look.  It'd be more of a mash up of my 2 charts.  Bars are summed up while Lines are broken out.